# How to calculate lot size

Tags: foreign-exchange

I am using MT4.

I would like to calculate lot size into my base currency depending on the asset. System sometimes gives me warning 'not enough money' when I want to place order. How is this calculated? Can I calculate this on my own somehow? How much money in my base currency is f.e. 0.5 lots of chosen asset?

Let's say I am trading crypto pair BAT/USD and want to know the value of 0.5 lots in EUR (my base currency), before I place order:

[image]

Comment: What did Metaquotes say when you asked them?

Comment: How to ask MT4?

Comment: They should have a website with support link and you just follow the process. Email, chat, forum, or whatnot. https://www.metaquotes.net/en/company/contacts see how easy that was, start there.